# Http failure during parsing in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing a crud, the backend is already working. I can read, add, update and delete with postman. But on the front-end, when I delete it, it shows the error: Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/locadora/delete/... but it deletes even though the error appears.

**app.component**

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Locadora } from './locadora';
import { LocadoraService} from './locadora.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'locadoraapp';
  public locacoes: Locadora[] = [];
  public editLocadora: Locadora | null;
  public deleteLocadora: Locadora | null;

  constructor ( private locadoraService: LocadoraService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getLocacoes();
  }

  public getLocacoes():void{
    this.locadoraService.getLocar().subscribe(
      (response: Locadora[])=>{
        this.locacoes = response;
      }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {alert(error.message)}
    
      )
     }
     

     public onAddLocadora(addForm: NgForm) : void{
      document.getElementById('add-locadora-form')?.click();
    
        this.locadoraService.addLocadora(addForm.value).subscribe(
          (response: Locadora) => {
            console.log(response)
            this.getLocacoes();
            addForm.reset();
    
          },
          (error: HttpErrorResponse)=>{
            alert(error.message)
          }
          )
        }
        public onUpdateLocadora(locadora: Locadora, locadoraId : string | undefined) :void{
        
          this.locadoraService.updateLocadora(locadoraId, locadora).subscribe(
            (response: Locadora)=>{
              console.log(response);
              this.getLocacoes();
            },
            (error: HttpErrorResponse)=>{
              alert(error.message)
            }
          )
          }
        
          public onDeleteLocadora(locadoraId: string | undefined) :void{
            
            this.locadoraService.deleteLocadora(locadoraId).subscribe(
              (response : void) =>{
                this.getLocacoes();
                }
            )
          }

     public onOpenModal(locadora: Locadora | null, mode: String): void{
      const container = document.getElementById('main-container')
      const button = document.createElement('button');
      button.type = 'button';
      button.style.display = 'none';
      button.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal')
      if(mode === 'add'){
        button.setAttribute('data-target', '#addLocadoraModal')
      }
      if(mode === 'update'){
        this.editLocadora = locadora;
        button.setAttribute('data-target', '#updateLocadoraModal')
      }
      if(mode === 'delete'){
        this.deleteLocadora = locadora;
        button.setAttribute('data-target', '#deleteLocadoraModal')
      }
      container?.appendChild(button);
      button.click();
    }






}
```

**service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.development';
import { Locadora } from "./locadora";
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocadoraService {
  private apiServerUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  public getLocar(): Observable<Locadora[]>{
      return this.http.get<Locadora[]>(`${this.apiServerUrl}locadora`)
  }

  public addLocadora(locadora: Locadora): Observable<Locadora>{
      return this.http.post<Locadora>(`${this.apiServerUrl}`, locadora)
  }

  public updateLocadora(locadoraId: string | undefined, locadora: Locadora): Observable<Locadora>{
      return this.http.put<Locadora>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/${locadoraId}`, locadora)
  }

  public deleteLocadora(locadoraId: string | undefined): Observable<void>{
      return this.http.delete<void>(`${this.apiServerUrl}locadora/delete/${locadoraId}`)
  }
 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- NavBar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;">Controle de Locação</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active"><!-- button add Employee -->
             <a class="nav-link" id="addbutton" (click)="onOpenModal(null, 'add')">Adicionar Locação <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
       </ul>
       <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input type="search" #key="ngModel" ngModel
           name="key" id="searchName" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Buscar locação..." required>
       </form>
    </div>
</nav>


<!-- Container Employees -->
<div class="container" id="main-container">
   <div class="row">
       <div *ngFor="let locadora of locacoes" class="col-md-6 col-xl-3" >
           <div class="card m-b-30">
               <div class="card-body row">
                   <div class="col-6">
                       
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-12 text-center mb-0">
                       <h5>{{locadora.filme}}</h5>
                       <p class="m-0"><b>Locação:</b> {{locadora.formatDateTime}}</p>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                   <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-envelope float-right"></i>Email : <a href="#">{{locadora.email}}</a></li>
                   <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-phone float-right"></i>Phone : {{locadora.telefone}}</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa fa-user float-right"></i>Responsável : {{locadora.responsavel}}</li>
               </ul>
               <div class="card-body col-12 text-center">
                   <div class="text-center btn-group btn-group-sm">
                     <a (click)="onOpenModal(locadora, 'update')" href="#" class="btn btn-primary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>
                     <a (click)="onOpenModal(locadora, 'delete')"href="#" class="btn btn-secondary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>    
   </div>
</div>

<!-- Add Employee Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addLocadoraModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addLocadoraModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="addLocadoraModalLabel">Adicionar Locação
            </h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <form #addForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddLocadora(addForm)">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="filme">Filme</label>
               <input type="text" ngModel name="filme" class="form-control" id="filme" placeholder="Filme" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tipo">Tipo:</label>
                <input type="text" ngModel name="tipo" class="form-control" id="tipo" placeholder="Tipo" required>
             </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="email">Email</label>
               <input type="email" ngModel name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="responsavel">Responsável</label>
               <input type="text" ngModel name="responsavel" class="form-control" id="responsavel" placeholder="Responsável" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
               <input type="text" ngModel name="telefone" class="form-control" id="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="formatDateTime">Dia e hora da locação</label>
               <input type="text" ngModel name="formatDateTime" class="form-control" id="formatDateTime" placeholder="Dia e hora da locação" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="endereco">Endereço</label>
                <input type="text" ngModel name="endereco" class="form-control" id="endereco" placeholder="endereco" required>
             </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
                <input type="text" ngModel name="cpf" class="form-control" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF" required>
             </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" id="add-locadora-form" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
               <button [disabled]="addForm.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Salvar</button>
            </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Edit Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="updateLocadoraModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="locadoraEditModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateLocadoraModalLabel">Editar Locação {{editLocadora?.filme}}</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <form #editForm="ngForm">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="filme">Filme</label>
                  <input type="text" ngModel="{{editLocadora?.filme}}" name="filme" class="form-control" id="filme" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Filme">
               </div>
               <input type="hidden" ngModel="{{editLocadora?.id}}" name="id" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Email">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="tipo">Tipo:</label>
                  <input type="tipo" ngModel="{{editLocadora?.email}}" name="tipo" class="form-control" id="tipo" placeholder="Tipo">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" ngModel="{{editLocadora?.email}}" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="responsavel">Responsavel</label>
                  <input type="text" ngModel="{{editLocadora?.responsavel}}" name="responsavel" class="form-control" id="responsavel" placeholder="Responsavel">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
                  <input type="text" ngModel="{{editLocadora?.telefone}}" name="telefone" class="form-control" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="dataLocacao">Dia e hora da locação</label>
                  <input type="text" ngModel="{{editLocadora?.dataLocacao}}" name="dataLocacao" class="form-control" id="dataLocacao" placeholder="dia da locação">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="formatDateTime">Dia e hora da locação</label>
                  <input type="text" ngModel="{{editLocadora?.formatDateTime}}" name="formatDateTime" class="form-control" id="formatDateTime" placeholder="dia e hora da locação">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="endereco">Endereço</label>
                  <input type="text" ngModel="{{editLocadora?.endereco}}" name="endereco" class="form-control" id="endereco" placeholder="Endereço">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
                  <input type="text" ngModel="{{editLocadora?.cpf}}" name="cpf" class="form-control" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF">
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" id="" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Fechar</button>
                  <button (click)="onUpdateLocadora(editForm.value,editLocadora?.id)" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" >Salvar</button>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>

  <!-- Delete Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="deleteLocadoraModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModelLabel">Deletar Locação</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Tem certeza que deseja deletar: {{deleteLocadora?.filme}}?</p>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Não</button>
               <button (click)="onDeleteLocadora(deleteLocadora?.id)" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Sim</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Error**

[error in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9wE3.png)

I tried in every way but I couldn't remove the error, at least it works even with the error

Comment: it works because the error is client-side and happens after the request has been sent. Your browser is (as the JS code told it to do) tries to parse the body sent back in response for that `DELETE` request as a JSON. well, It isn't a json, so the parser failes.

Comment: And how do I resolve this error?

Comment: well, you either change the backend so it returns a JSON object in response to those DELETE requests, or, you remove the attempt to parse the response as a JSON in the frontend. Currently the response is "Registro a...."

Comment: Solved, it was a problem with the body in the backend